# How to get React HighCharts to work with TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to get the official React npm package for HighCharts to work. I am using TypeScript in my project and I get the following error when trying to use the charts.

Type 'HighchartsReact' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, and 2 more.  TS2605

I've tried using an example similar to what is listed as the TypeScript solution for the package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official

```
import Highcharts from 'highcharts'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'

class App extends React.Component<any, any> {
  private _dataOrderService: DataOrdering;
  private originalCars: Car [];

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);


    const options = {
      title: {
        text: 'My chart'
      },
      series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3]
      }]
    }

    this.state = {
      cars: [],
      originalCars: [],
      ordering: ["Make", "Model", "Year"],
      originalOrdering: ["Make", "Model", "Year"],
      dealershipInfo: [],
      showAddCarModal: false,
      showColumnOrderModal: false,
      searchTerm: "",
      highChartOptions: options
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <div id="chart">
          <HighchartsReact
            highcharts={Highcharts} 
            options={this.state.options}
          />
          </div>
</div>);
}
```

Here is the error I keep getting.
Type 'HighchartsReact' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, and 2 more.  TS2605

I've already tried using this approach using the spread operator as suggested on the documentation for this package.

Example:

```
const App = (props: HighchartsReact.Props) => <div>
    <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={options}
        {...props}
    />
</div>
```

This above code segment still resulted in the same error occurring that I've described.

Comment: Can you show us, how you implement options in the second example?

Comment: Hi @MisterTams, Could you reproduce that issue in some online code editor? I have tested a standard example and it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-awshj3?file=index.tsx

Comment: @Domino987, Take a look at the example below your comment posted by ppotaczek. I literally tried this same code and it blows up with the same error.

Comment: @ppotaczek. I created a new project and copied and pasted your code from the online code editor. Did a npm install. Same error regardless. It definitely works in the online version.

Comment: The error also mentions something about the following: JSX element type 'HighchartsReact' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.

Comment: It seems like the problem is with your modules not your code. What version are you using?